# Ceiling lights wired in series?

Tags: led

A friend complained that all five of the recessed LED lights in her kitchen were out. The circuit breaker was good. My friend suggested replacing one of the LED units.

We did this and all the lights came back on. Is it possible the lights are wired in series?

I noticed when I replaced the LED unit that there was only a single pair of wires in the junction box (one hot, one neutral). I thought that fixture might be at the end of a run, but now I'm thinking it was series wiring.

I've done basic home wiring for many years and I've never seen this configuration. Is that how it's being done now?

Comment: I've never come across household lights being wired in series.... maybe Christmas  mini string light but that's it.  I've run into many fixtures with a single black and single white wire in it and had them all joined in a remote junction box. Try taking out some of the other bulbs, one at a time   and see if you lose all the lights.

Comment: No, nobody does series wiring but rank novices and it's called "a mistake".  In fact, every box except the last MUST have 2 cables (4 wires + grounds) because of NEC 300.3, even if series wiring were legitimate, the return current must come back in the same cable. No loops allowed in AC mains. (except in the UK but that is a weird exception).

Comment: The problem with series wiring is most devices won’t work, however, LED’s  require much lower voltage so they may. If incandescent lamps were used 5 they would barely glow compared to normal wiring.